# How can I read Caller ID information in a Cocoa app?

Tags: cocoa, telephony, phone-call, modem

Specifically, I have the Apple USB modem that says it supports Caller ID and I want my app to be able to know when a call comes in and whose calling.  In the future I may add dialer capabilities, etc., but cart-before-the-horse.  Caller ID is stop-one!

That said, I can't believe this has proven sooo ellusive to find even a single example of ANYWHERE (I have googled the CRAP out of this!) but can anyone show me how to do basic Caller ID detection in a Mac app?  I'd prefer Cocoa but will be willing to go Carbon if I must.

Now I'm not looking for a full-on telephony API example although again, I'll go that route if I have to, but I can't even find that!  Found this all over the place on the Windows side of things, but can't find a damn thing on Mac!

Comment: Can I suggest you make one of your tags "modem" or at least mention it somewhat earlier in the question? It took me a while to realise what you were actually wanting.

Comment: Mike, the modem is secondary. I mentioned it because that's what I have but if there's another way to get Caller ID from my home line into an app, I'm all for it.  After all, not just modems do this.  I have a serial-port based caller ID box that isn't a modem but does read caller ID information.  But if there's a USB something or other, or anything else that can get me caller ID, that's what I'm ultimately after.  The guts of the black box don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [elsewhere](http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/MacOS_X#Connecting_a_Mac_and_an_Openmoko_device) you can (and I have) use `screen /dev/tty.usbmodem00001` or some such to access the modem directly from terminal, send AT commands or see RINGs and CallerID (once enabled via AT or NCID).
They also walk through minicom usage as mentioned above.

Googling `/dev/tty mac callerid` reveals quite a few ideas.

As to writing software, I imagine NCID will either prove useful (there's a growl plugin too!) or can serve as example code. See [the Mac install instructions](http://ncid.sourceforge.net/ncid/INSTALL-Mac.txt), specifically under `TEST USING A MODEM`. Here's [an example way of extending NCID to launch your own program/script with CallerID info.](http://ncid.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/ncid/ncid/file/tip/modules/ncid-skel.sh)

Answer (score 0):

Man, that is going old school. I haven't seen anything related to analog modems in five years. I know that back in the day, even the NextStep modem stuff was down in the BSD and written in C. I don't think there ever was Objective-C API for it all. Today, everything is volIP.

[Asterisks](http://asterisk.darwinports.com/) looks like something you might be able to use.

Comment: Ya... that's the problem.  I've looked into getting caller ID from bluetooth devices from cell phones but to no avail.  I've also looked into VOIP stuff but asides from Skype or another app, most VOIP hardware just converts the signals back to POTS lines so you can still use your regular phones, hence you're right back to te beginning.

As I said in a reply to the 'modem' comment above, the end-game is I want somehow to get a caller ID notification.  Don't really care how or over what method.  Just need to get it.  You can show me any solution, I'm all for it.

Comment: I think it's going to be hard. People just aren't doing a lot of that kind of work anymore. I suggest you look for some Posix compatible Linux solutions and try to port them over. There's a lot of hardware hacking on the Linux side.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to talk to the modem with [`Hayes`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) commands? Then I think you should be able to enable the caller id feature with

```
AT#CID=1
```

If you need a terminal program to talk to the modem with I can recommend [`minicom`](https://alioth.debian.org/frs/?group_id=30018). I got it to compile for the mac just now with

```
LIBS=-liconv ./configure ; make ; sudo make install
```

I'm not sure how the caller id will be presented but I think using the terminal program you should be able to see it probably when the `RING` is outputed from the modem.

All new to this? Maybe this can be a [start](http://www.bigwebmaster.com/General/Howtos/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/modem-hayes.html)

Then back to Cocoa, how to *speak* to a modem? See this [discussion](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BestWayToWriteToBSDDevice)

This [page](http://www.frontiernet.net/~fys/modminfo.htm) has a discussion about the caller id, *interesting*. Apparently the caller id and more is outputted after the first `RING`

Comment: IF I could get that far that would be great... but I haven't found any wasy way to even get to the COM ports to send the commands down.  I'm working through the Apple sample that supposedly enumerates serial ports, but I can't get anything more than a generic response from querying the system what modems/ports are attached and the modem and it fails when I try to open the port anyway.  If you know of any Mac code for talking to a USB modem, or even just a COM port, I'd love to see it!  Would be a huuuge help!

Comment: @MarqueIV This sample code should get you going http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SerialPortSample/ You should notice the AT commands defined early in the .c file

Answer (score -1):

It's much harder than you'd think because there's no API to control the modem.

Asterisk referred by TechZen above is a good reference, but Asterisk has no driver for the USB modem you're trying to use. The folks over at *sunrisetel* started an effort to write a driver for Apple's USB modem but I'm not sure if they have not abandoned it in the meantime: [see afelio](http://www.sunrisetel.net/software/afelio/afelio.shtml)

Quoting from Afelio's page:

> A media server for the Motorola SM56 modem used by Apple in recent Macs and in the external Apple USB modem is now under development.